# Endomorphism algebra of subrepresentation of regular representation of $S_3$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G = S_3$. Then the regular representation $\mathbb{C}[G]$ decomposes as $\mathbb{C}[G] = \mathbb{C}\oplus \epsilon \oplus V \oplus V$, where $\mathbb{C}$ and $\epsilon$ are the trivial and nontrivial 1d representations, and $V$ is the 2d irrep. What is the endomorphism algebra of $V\oplus V$?

I thought it was the matrix algebra $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, because the composition $V \rightarrow V\oplus V \rightarrow V$ of the inclusion and projection onto a direct summand should be a scalar by Schur's lemma. Or, using the description of the $V$-isotypic subspace as $V\otimes V^\ast$, the endomorphism algebra is $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C} V^\ast = M_2(\mathbb C)$.

However, the discussion in the comments of [another post of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444536/understanding-the-proof-of-the-springer-correspondence?noredirect=1#comment1147814_444536) suggests to me that the endomorphism algebra should be only 1-dimensional. How can I see this? What is wrong with my argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the endomorphism algebra being a matrix algebra, for exactly the reason you describe. The way to keep track of this is to always bear in mind whether you are computing as modules, or bimodules.

For instance, $V\otimes V^*$ as a left $G$ module on the first factor is $\dim V$ copies of $V$. It is also naturally as $G-G$ bimodule though, and as a $G-G$ bimodule it is simple.

So if we have some object $M$ with endomorphism ring $E$ the group algebra of some group $W$, this tells us that $E$ splits as a product of matrix algebras indexed by irreps. Our object $M$ then splits into pieces $M_\chi$ indexed by irreps of $W$, being the images in $M$ of these primitive idempotents of $k[W]$ under our isomorphism with $E$.

Then we note that each $M_\chi$ has endomorphism ring $M_{\dim V\times \dim V}(k)$ (using that our group algebra breaks into a product of matrix algebras).

But now we have a general lemma that if $N$ is any object in a $k$ linear additive category with endomorphisms $M_{n\times n}(k)$, then $N$ is canonically isomorphic to $U_n\otimes N’$, where the action of $M_{n\times n}(k)$ is solely on the first factor, the usual $n$ dimensional representation of matrices (note tensoring with a vector space makes sense in this generality). I believe this general lemma is what Geordie was alluding to, and is what let’s us find these smaller objects in our category with the desired homs between them.

It’s worth running through all steps of this general theory in an example, such as the regular representation of a finite group in the category of $G$ representations.

This gives the statement of the proof, but bear in mind we still don’t know that these perverse sheaves are simple,as in general $End(M)=k$ doesn’t imply simplicity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I think I understand now - in the case of $S_3$, one has $U_n \otimes N' = V^\ast \otimes V$, i.e. $M_2(\mathbb C)$ acts by its defining representation on $V^\ast$ and $\mathrm{End}(V) = \mathbb C$.